# -1 fixed channel on mon0 in aircrack

Tags: linux, ubuntu-11.04, aircrack-ng

I installed recently aircrack 1.1 and when I enable my wlan card into monitor mode by airmon-ng start wlan0 6 I always get fixed channel -1. Anybody knows how to fix it?

My wifi card is Ethernet controller: Atheros Communications Inc. AR5007G Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01). And linux ver 2.6.38-12-generic.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is a compatibility issue between `mac80211 kernel subsystem` and `aircrack-ng`. It landed in mainline linux kernel 2.6.35 and appears to have been there ever since (writing this on kernel 3.1).

There's two workarounds. You can either patch `aircrack-ng` or wifi drivers. I prefer the latter since it's very simple and, as a side-effect, gives you most recent drivers.

Here's the recipe:

```
# we need kernel headers and a toolchain to build wifi drivers 
sudo apt-get install build-essentials linux-headers-2.6.38-12-generic

# download current wireless driver source tree
wget http://linuxwireless.org/download/compat-wireless-2.6/compat-wireless-2.6.tar.bz2

# uncompress
tar xjf compat-wireless-2.6.tar.bz2

# download patch that fixes the problem
wget http://patches.aircrack-ng.org/channel-negative-one-maxim.patch

# apply patch
cd compat-wireless-20*
patch -p1 < ../channel-negative-one-maxim.patch

# compile and install
make
sudo make install

# follow simple instructions to reload the drivers without reboot. Eg:
sudo make unload
sudo modprobe ath5k
```

For some background see here:
http://trac.aircrack-ng.org/ticket/742

Comment: Just a follow-up for anyone else that comes across this issue, it *has* been fixed in the latest versions of `aircrack-ng` and `compat-wireless`.  See [this wiki article](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compat-wireless) for how to compile your own drivers.